# if a ball is hitting a box from every side, how to know which side hittest is true

Tags: actionscript-3, game-physics

i am creating a brick breaker game in which ball is hitting a square object. i want to change the direction of ball when he hit square object.
square is of 15 px. and
ball is of 10 px.
 for example

if hits on the right side, Speed in x direction will reverse 
if hits on the left side, Speed in x direction will reverse 
if hits on the up side, Speed in y direction will reverse 
if hits on the down side , Speed in y direction will reverse.

I tried it hard but found nothing. any help will be appreciated. here is the code:

```
      import flash.events.*;
      import flash.display.*;

       stop();
```

// speed of ball in x and y

```
       var speedx : Number = 10;
       var speedy : Number = 10;
```

// start running

```
       function begin_code (event:MouseEvent):void{

       addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move_ball);

       stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,by_key);
       addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,ht_mc);
       start_game.alpha=0;
       }
       start_game.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, begin_code) ;
```

//start ball moving

```
  function move_ball(e:Event):void{

Ball.x += speedx;
Ball.y += speedy;
Ball.rotation +=speedx;

var ballposition : Number = Ball.x -Hitbar.x;
var ballhitpercent : Number = (ballposition /(Hitbar.width-Ball.width));

if(Ball.x <= x1.x+Ball.width/2){
    speedx = speedx *-1;
}
 if(Ball.x >= x2.x-Ball.width/2){
    speedx = speedx *-1;
}
 if(Ball.y <=(55)){

    speedy = speedy *-1;

}
else if (Ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-Ball.height){ 
speedy = speedy *-1;
trace("hit y");

}
//start ball angle
else if(Ball.hitTestObject(Hitbar)){ 
    speedx = ballhitpercent*10;
    speedy = speedy *-1;    
}
 }
```

//start hitbar moving

// code for keys!!!!!!!!!

```
    var distance : Number = 0;

    function by_key(e:MouseEvent):void{

    if (mouseX>Hitbar.x){

    distance = (mouseX-Hitbar.x);
    Hitbar.x += distance;
}

else if (mouseX<Hitbar.x){
distance = (Hitbar.x-mouseX);
Hitbar.x -= distance;
}
}
```

//restart

```
  function by_key_up(e:MouseEvent):void{
  } 

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, by_key_up);

  function pLimiter(e:Event):void{
  Hitbar.y = 406.2;

  if (Hitbar.hitTestObject(x1)){
     Hitbar.x = 32.6;
}

   if (Hitbar.hitTestObject(x2)){
     Hitbar.x = 287.55;
}   
}

  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, pLimiter);
```

// Bricks set hit

```
    var pickup:Array =new Array();

    for (var i = 0;i<numChildren;i++){
if(getChildAt(i) is abc){
    pickup.push(getChildAt(i));
}
}

   function hittest_box(e:Event):void{
for (var f = 0;f<pickup.length;f++){
if (Ball.hitTestObject(pickup[f])){
if(pickup[f].parent) {
    pickup[f].parent.removeChild(pickup[f]);
}
    }   
   }
   }
    function ht_mc(e:Event):void{
     for (var j = 0;j<pickup.length;j++){
    var ball_pos_x: Number = ( Ball.x - pickup[j].x); 
    var ball_pos_y: Number = ( Ball.y - pickup[j].y); 

     if( ball_pos_x < 11.5 && ball_pos_x > -11.5){
             speedy = speedy *-1;
             trace("box y");
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hittest_box);

    }
    else if ( ball_pos_y < 11.5 && ball_pos_y > -11.5){
             speedx = speedx *-1;
              trace("boxx");
   addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hittest_box);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks neal, please let me know if something is there. I am also trying to do it with hit percentage method.

Comment: Sir Neal do you have any update?

Comment: I can keep working in it tonight. It's in line with another project I was working on so I don't mind taking the time to get it right. I'll tell you where I'm headed though in case you want to try to figure it out also. I think we need a function that determines if the path of the ball intersects an edge of a block, and if so, which one. I think the smartest way to do this will be with vector math, which is very weird stuff to me. So we need to consider each corner of the block as an end point of a line segment, and the start and end pos. of the ball as end points of the other line segment.

Comment: ok please tell me if you have and may be hitTestPoint is a good method to find the intersection of edges

Comment: hitTestPoint won't work for what I'm thinking because the real problem (that may not be a problem in your case) is that the ball could jump over a corner of the brick from one frame to the next. To get this truly right, we can't rely on a hitTest.  With a line calculation we can know every point the ball was at "in between" frames

Comment: please do .....

Comment: Posted my answer.  I did it without vector math (cross product or dot product is not easy to grok for me).  Of course you'll have to implement it to your project, but the foundation is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

To turn my two point example into a one-ball-moving version, the main thing you need to do is to declare the `p1` then move the ball and then declare `p2`.

```
p1.x = ball.x;
p1.y = ball.y;
moveBall();
p2.x = ball.x;
p2.y = ball.y;
```

Now you have p1 and p2. Run the calculations as below to find which brick is hit and which side was hit.

A few more calculations will be needed (and you'll have to loop through this whole thing for every collision that occurs in between frames). But I can't post all that here.

### Original Answer

[image: swf]

My answer is meant to be able to be used in any situation in which you have a point object that is moving and needs to detect when it collides with sides of a square.  Simple hitTest solutions are inadequate because a point object moving fast enough could "jump over" a corner.  Additionally, if the walls of the object are infinitely thin, there couldn't easily be a "collision", so what we really want to calculate is whether or not the point passed through a wall during the last tick.  Also, if the ball is going fast enough to jump over an entire brick, you'll get collision with bricks that are surrounded by other bricks.  This method fixes that.  Here we go...

[image: edge detection]

My illustration shows the basic method I'm using.  It breaks down like this:

1. define end points for each line segment (corners of block and 2 positions of ball)
2. check first if ball bounding box and block overlap with simple hit test type of conditional statement
3. if they do, determine which edge the ball passed through by comparing the 3 angles as shown in the diagram (angle 1 just has to be between angle 2 and 3)
4. then determine which of the points that make up the lines that the ball passed through during the last frame transition and determine which of these points is nearest the where the ball was on the previous frame (this will be a point contained in the line that the ball will hit!)
5. lastly, determine which line contains that point

There could certainly be some optimizations added, but this works like a charm for what it is.

This code will add a bunch of `LineTestBlock` objects to the stage as well as 2 `Point` objects associated with circles.  Move the `Points` such that `1` will represent the first frame location of the ball, and the second `Point` can be dragged to a place representing where the ball will be on the 2nd frame.  You will see that wherever the line between these passes through, the closest edge of a block will light up.

And here is the code.  It is a main document class named `BlockDoc` and a `LineTestBlock` class.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.Shape;


public class BlockDoc extends MovieClip {

    // this holds the circle handles (the actual sprite objects)
    var cArray = new Array();
    // this holds all the bricks
    var brickArray = new Array();
    //ball position in frame 1
    //these are just point objects. p1 will need to represent where the ball was on the last frame
    var p1:Point = new Point();
    // and p2 will need to be where the ball is "going" to be on the next frame
    // although, if it hits something, the ball will not end up p2 on the next screen update, obviously
    var p2:Point = new Point();
    // just an array used for putting the 1 and 2 on  the handles
    // you won't eventually need this, of course
    var pointNameArray:Array = new Array();

    // this is the Sprite object that holds the rectangle 
    // which describes the bounding box made by the ball in the two frames                  
    var recASprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    // rec is the Sprite that holds the bricks, or you could just put the bricks on the stage.  I like having them in a container so I can remove them all or move them all or change them all just by changing the container
    var rec:Sprite = new Sprite();
    // lines is the Shape object that all the bricks edge lines are drawn to
    var lines:Shape = new Shape();
    // mainLine is the Shape object that the line connecting the two ball positions is drawn to
    var mainLine:Shape = new Shape();
    // you won't need either of these lines in your version

    public function BlockDoc() {

        // just a background so you can see the alpha better. 
        // you won't need this in yours
        var bkgnd:Sprite = new Sprite();
        bkgnd.graphics.lineStyle();
        bkgnd.graphics.beginFill(0x0);
        bkgnd.graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
        bkgnd.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(bkgnd);


        makeBricks();   
        createArray();
        addChild(mainLine);
        addChild(lines);
        createHandles(); // creates the circle handles
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameTick);
    }

    private function drawLine(container:Shape,p1:Point,p2:Point,color:uint=0xffbbee):void{
        container.graphics.clear();
        container.graphics.lineStyle(2,color);
        container.graphics.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
        container.graphics.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
    }

    private function makeBricks():void{ 

        // creates rectangle object defined by frame 1 and 2 of ball position
        updateBallBoundingBox(recASprite,p1,p2);
        addChild(rec); // the parent for all bounding boxes
        makeSimpleRectangle(recASprite); // this is the bounding box for the 2 positions of the ball
        // these are the bricks
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++){
            for (var j: int = 0; j < 3; j++){
                var b: LineTestBlock = new LineTestBlock(50,25);
                rec.addChild(b);
                b.alpha = .5;
                brickArray.push(b);
                b.x = 100 * i + 50;
                b.y = 80 * j +100;  

                // top left corner of brick
                b._p1.x = b.x;
                b._p1.y = b.y;

                // top right corner of brick
                b._p2.x = b.x + b.width;
                b._p2.y = b.y;

                // bottom right corner of brick
                b._p3.x = b.x + b.width;
                b._p3.y = b.y + b.height;

                // bottom left corner of brick
                b._p4.x = b.x;
                b._p4.y = b.y + b.height;
            }
        }
    }

    private function makeSimpleRectangle(rect:Sprite,color:uint = 0x0):void{

        rect.graphics.lineStyle(0,0x0,0);
        rect.graphics.beginFill(color,.5);
        rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
        rect.graphics.endFill();
    }

    private function updateBallBoundingBox(rec:Sprite,p1:Point,p2:Point):void{
        rec.x = Math.min(p2.x,p1.x);
        rec.y = Math.min(p2.y,p1.y);
        rec.width = Math.max(p2.x,p1.x)-rec.x;
        rec.height = Math.max(p2.y,p1.y)-rec.y;
    }

    private function checkIntersection(A1:Point,A2:Point,B1:Point,B2:Point):Boolean{

        // adjusts the current "bounding box" using the position 1 and position 2 of the ball
        updateBallBoundingBox(recASprite,A1,A2);

        // if bounding boxes hit
        // define the angles to be used (further optimization can easily be done here by
        // only checking the 2 possible sides of contact, or using a look up table 
        // instead of using Math.atan2)

        // angle between position 1 and 2 of the ball
        var A1_A2_r:Number = Math.atan2(A2.y - A1.y,A2.x - A1.x);
        // angle between position 1 and one corner
        var A1_B1_r:Number = Math.atan2(B1.y - A1.y,B1.x - A1.x);
        // angle between position 1 and the second corner
        var A1_B2_r:Number = Math.atan2(B2.y - A1.y,B2.x - A1.x);
        // and if angle from position 1 to position 2 is between angle from one corner to the other corner...
        if (A1_A2_r > A1_B1_r && A1_A2_r < A1_B2_r){
            // return true
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function gameTick(e:Event):void{
        // p1 and p2 are the point objects that describe frame 1 and frame 2 of the moving ball
               // for actual moving ball:
               //p1.x = Ball.x; 
               //p1.y = Ball.y;
               //move_ball();
               //p2.x = Ball.x;
               //p2.y = Ball.y;
               //or use this for experimenting with the handles
        //p1.x = cArray[0].x;
        //p1.y = cArray[0].y;
        //p2.x = cArray[1].x;
        //p2.y = cArray[1].y;
        // draw line between position 1 and 2
        drawLine(mainLine,p1,p2);
        checkCollision();
    }

    private function checkCollision():void{

        // clears previously drawn lines on bricks
        lines.graphics.clear();
        var xDir:int;
        var yDir:int;
        // determine direction of ball (you probably already have this as a variable somewhere so probably don't need this
        if (p1.x < p2.x){
            xDir = 1;
        } else if (p1.x > p2.x){
            xDir = -1;
        } else {
            xDir = 0;
        }
        if (p1.y < p2.y){
            yDir = 1;
        } else if (p1.y > p2.y){
            yDir = -1;
        } else {
            yDir = 0;
        }   

        // this array will hold all the Point objects involved in true collision
        var arr:Array = new Array();
        var arrLines:Array = new Array();
        var nearestDistance:Number = 2000; // change this to something sensible (maybe the speed of the ball...);
        var nearestPoint:Point = new Point(); // change this to something sensible
        // first check bounding boxes       
        for (var i:int = 0; i < brickArray.length; i++){
            var b:LineTestBlock = brickArray[i];                
            var a:Sprite = recASprite;
            updateBallBoundingBox(a,p2,p1);
            // this is just a bounding box hittest, and hitTestObject used to work, but I broke something, so I have to do it like this now
            if (a.x+a.width > b.x && a.y + a.height > b.y && a.x < b.x+b.width && a.y<b.y+b.height){

                // now that we know the rectangles overlap, we check the two sides that are hittable
                // instead of xDir and yDir just use your variable or property that holds the x and y speeds;
                // I use xDir and yDir because my example doesn't actually use motion.
                if (xDir > 0){
                    if (checkIntersection(p1,p2,b._p1,b._p4)){
                        // ball hits left wall of brick
                        //drawLine(lines,b._p1,b._p4,0x00ffee);
                        // instead of drawLine above, put in your function for collision of left wall
                        arr.push(b._p1,b._p4);
                        arrLines.push({p1:b._p1,p2:b._p4,brick:brickArray[i]});
                        // that last array there simply holds an object with 3 properties 
                        // for use later in comparing what should actually receive the hit.
                    }
                    if (yDir > 0) {
                        if (checkIntersection(p2,p1,b._p1,b._p2)){
                            // ball hits top wall of brick
                            arr.push(b._p1,b._p2);
                            arrLines.push({p1:b._p1,p2:b._p2,brick:brickArray[i]});
                        }
                    } else if (yDir < 0){
                        if(checkIntersection(p2,p1,b._p3,b._p4)){
                            // ball hits bottom wall of brick
                            arr.push(b._p3,b._p4);  
                            arrLines.push({p1:b._p3,p2:b._p4,brick:brickArray[i]});                                
                        }
                    }
                } else if (xDir < 0){
                    if(checkIntersection(p2,p1,b._p2,b._p3)){
                        // ball hits right edge of brick
                        arr.push(b._p2,b._p3);
                        arrLines.push({p1:b._p2,p2:b._p3,brick:brickArray[i]});
                    } 
                    if (yDir > 0) {
                        if (checkIntersection(p2,p1,b._p1,b._p2)){
                            // ball hits top edge of brick
                            arr.push(b._p1,b._p2);
                            arrLines.push({p1:b._p1,p2:b._p2,brick:brickArray[i]});
                        }
                    } else if (yDir < 0){
                        if(checkIntersection(p2,p1,b._p3,b._p4)){
                            // ball hits bottom edge of brick
                            arr.push(b._p3,b._p4);
                            arrLines.push({p1:b._p3,p2:b._p4,brick:brickArray[i]}); 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i:int = 0; i < brickArray.length; i++){
            brickArray[i].alpha = 0.3;
        }
        for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            var d:Number = dist(arr[i],p1);
            if(d < nearestDistance){
                nearestDistance = d;
                nearestPoint = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (var j:int = 0; j < arrLines.length; j++){
            if (arrLines[j].p1 == nearestPoint){
                drawLine(lines,nearestPoint,arrLines[j].p2);//THIS IS THE EDGE THAT GETS HIT!!
                arrLines[j].brick.alpha = 0.7; // THIS IS THE BRICK THAT GETS HIT!!
            } else if (arrLines[j].p2 == nearestPoint){
                drawLine(lines,nearestPoint,arrLines[j].p1); //THIS IS THE EDGE THAT GETS HIT!!
                arrLines[j].brick.alpha = 0.7; // THIS IS THE BRICK THAT GETS HIT!!
            }
        }           
    }

    private function dist(p1:Point, p2:Point):Number{
        var dx:Number = p1.x - p2.x;
        var dy:Number = p1.y - p2.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    private function createHandles():void{

        // these are the circle handles for moving the balls around
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 2; i++){
            var c:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();

            c.graphics.lineStyle();
            c.graphics.beginFill(0x5555ff+0x5555*i);
            c.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
            c.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(c);
            c.addChild(tf);
            c.x = 50*i+50;
            c.y = 50;
            c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragObject);
            c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragStopObject);
            cArray.push(c);

            tf.height = 20;
            tf.width = 10;
            tf.text = pointNameArray[i];
            tf.x = -5;
            tf.y = -10;
            tf.mouseEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    private function createArray():void{
        // just used for putting the fancy 1 and 2 on the handles
        pointNameArray = ["1","2"];
    }

    private function radsFromPoints(p1:Point,p2:Point):Number{
        return Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.y);
    }

    private function dragObject(me:MouseEvent):void{
        me.target.startDrag(true);
    }

    private function dragStopObject(me:MouseEvent):void{
        me.target.stopDrag();
    }
}   
}
```

and the `LineTestBlock` class:

```
package  {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class LineTestBlock extends Sprite{

    var _p1:Point = new Point();
    var _p2:Point = new Point();
    var _p3:Point = new Point();
    var _p4:Point = new Point();

    public function LineTestBlock(w:Number,h:Number) {

        var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
        s.graphics.lineStyle();
        s.graphics.beginFill(0xff5599,0.5);
        s.graphics.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
        s.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(s);
    }       
}
}
```

Obviously the stuff about lines and alpha are just for display purposes.  You'll be able to erase a bunch of this code and will need to replace some of it with actual bounce functions.

One thing to keep in mind is how you deal with the bouncing off of the ball. You can't simply reverse the x or y speed of the ball, as you might think because then it is inside of a brick, or on the opposite side of the  brick trying to come back out, which will work, but could look funny and actually allow the ball access to bricks that should be off limits because the are surrounded by other bricks.  But I've already answered the question at hand, so I'll stop there.

Comment: thanks this looks truly good. I am trying it with a new flash file so i can see how it works but nothing happened. May be i am forgetting something as i am just a beginner.also i have created a box in library name LineTestBlock to link with class file LineTestBlock.

Comment: Don't create a box in library. Everything is done at runtime. You just need to create an fla file named `BlockDoc` and paste my code. Then create a `.as` file named `LineTestBlock` and paste my second code. Put both of these files in the same folder. Then test the movie.

Comment: but your 1st code is also class file code so is it possible to paste it in .fla file.after doing so there is a error called:package can not be nested.

Comment: Neal can you help me with ball . i am  confuse that how can i add a ball there? in order to add a moving ball i have to replace it with one point.

Comment: So did you get yours working to where the ball can bounce off all sides?

Comment: Yes. Where are you at on it? What exactly do you need help with?  I think I answered the question here regarding how to detect which side is being hit. Can you post a new question or explain how this answer doesn't answer your question?

Comment: Neal your answer is about 2 points and i asked you to add a moving ball there for 2nd point and also there is no first point. your answer can not help me if can not add a moving ball there.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion I posted a week ago at the top of the answer marked "edit"? That's what I did and my ball works fine now.

Comment: Neal what you did ? can you please explain because i have tried many things but result is not good .

Comment: Kindly update your original post with the ball movement code you are using and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: I updated my answer for you to include the ball movement (import your own move_ball function but remove the (e:Event) part because I'm now calling the function inside of a gameTick function). This works, trust me. Just spend some time with it and let me know if you have any specific questions or problems, and in the future, don't mark an answer as correct unless you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Accept my apology Sir, i am new to this site and i did not realize when you updated the answer before. notification comes only for comments not for updated answer. Now i see your idea so let me do it.

Comment: How'd it go? Here's a link to my finished product. http://ultineprojects.weebly.com/